# Enter A DNS name for site hosted

Tags: web-hosting, internal-dns, dns-hosting

I have setup a website on a Mac server 10.5.8, i would like to be accessible over the internet, I need to enter a DNS entry for the website on the Mac server. How do I do this?

I would like to create

```
internal.example.com
```

example.com has already been set.

internal is a folder running on a mac server in the Documents part for webhosting

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need a static IP address for your server, one which will never change. Once you have this, you should be able to change the DNS with your domain registrar unless you have changed the nameservers. Go to http://who.is/whois/yourdomain.com/ to view the Registrar and Nameserver information.
The registrar is the company that controls your domain, and as such the company you need to change any details (such as registrant information or nameservers) with.
The nameservers tell you who handles the DNS for your domain, which will likely be the domain registrar as mentioned above.
Go to wherever your domain is setup (again, probably your registrar control panel), and add an A Record for yourdomain.com pointing to your static IP address. Also add one for www.yourdomain.com.
If you do not have a static IP, there are services such as [no-ip](http://www.no-ip.com/) to provide dynamic DNS, but I can't speak from experience about them.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the DNS is completely unrelated to your server configuration - it points to the IP address and nothing else. It might be worth removing the macosxserver tag from this question and open it up to a wider audience.

Comment: Also worth noting is the need to configure vhosts on the server if it's going to run more than one website.